# Passing selected values out of my view into a list

Tags: asp.net-mvc, listbox, multi-select

So I'm new to asp.net MVC 4 programmming, and I've bumped into another problem.

This is my model class:

```
public class OtherMeeting
{
public int OtherMeetingId { get; set; }
[Required(ErrorMessage="Name is required")]
public String Name { get; set; }
[Required(ErrorMessage="Location is required")]
public String Location { get; set; }
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[Required(ErrorMessage="Date is required")]
public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DateGreaterThan("StartDate")]
public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
public int CountryId { get; set; }
public virtual Country Country { get; set; }
public Type Type { get; set; }

public int EventId { get; set; }
public List<Event> Events { get; set; }
}
```

It's the List field that's giving me problems.

I have the following code in my controller:

```
public ActionResult Create()
    {
      ViewBag.EventId = new MultiSelectList(db.Events, "EventId", "Discipline");
      ViewBag.CountryId = new MultiSelectList(db.Countries, "CountryId", "CountryName");
      return View();
    }
```

This is the code I have in my view ( I left out the editors for the other fields, they all work as they should):

```
 <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.Label("Add Events")
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.ListBox("EventId")   
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Events)                      
  </div>
```

This is my postback method in the controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(OtherMeeting otherMeeting)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {               
            db.OtherMeetings.Add(otherMeeting);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        ViewBag.EventId = new MultiSelectList(db.Events, "EventId", "Discipline");
        ViewBag.CountryId = new MultiSelectList(db.Countries, "CountryId", "CountryName");
        return View(otherMeeting);
    }
```

Now obviously the List Events field will still be a null reference, so I was wondering, how do I add the items I have selected to the List Events field. I have done some research on the internet but all I get are complex solutions like FormCollections, using JQuery, etc.. It should be solveable in a pretty simple way since this is all for a school-project, and they don't expect us to use JQuery or advanced programming. I had also been thinking to add a button next to the EventListBox so that when I click it, the selected items will be passed to a temporary List outside the view that I can later use to fill the original list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `ListBoxFor` select extension.

First, define a view model for your events - don't just use your domain model (database) classes.

```
public class EventViewModel
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Now change your existing view model to have the following (everything for the view *really* should be in the model since *that's what it's for* - avoid `ViewBag` where you can):

```
public List<EventViewModel> Events { get; set; }
public List<int> EventIds { get; set; }
```

Now, in your first controller method, instantiate the model and list and fill it with `Event` objects:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
  var model = new OtherMeeting();
  foreach (Event e in db.Events)
  {
      var eventModel = new EventViewModel {
          Id = e.EventId,
          Name = e.Discipline
      };
      model.Events.Add(eventModel);
  }

  return View(model);
}
```

Now create your multiselectlist in your view, define the value and description fields and pass in `Model.EventIds` as the list of selected items:

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.EventIds,
    new MultiSelectList(Model.Events, "Id", "Name", Model.EventIds))
```

Now, in your post request, you can just access `otherMeeting.EventIds` for the list of selected events.

This is the "conventional" way of doing this in ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: This answer is baed on the assumption that the Event class only has an id and discipline field right?

Comment: @RobinHellemans Not necessarily - it's based on the assumption that those are the only fields that are needed for your view. Create a new ViewModel that has only those fields and populate them from `Event` objects in your controller as I did in my `Create` method above. You shouldn't expose your domain entities to your view.

Comment: Allright, I'm having some trouble understanding exactly what it is you're doing though. This part of the code: 

    public ActionResult Create()
    {
  var model = new OtherMeeting();
    foreach (Event e in db.Events)
    {
      var eventModel = new EventViewModel {
          Id = e.EventId,
          Name = e.Discipline
      };
      model.Events.Add(eventModel);
  }

    return View(model);
    }
 
As I see it I'm adding EventViewModel objects to my List<Event> Events field. But an Event has multiple fields, so it would just add null for the other fields? What if they're not nullable?

Comment: No, `EventViewModel` is a completely separate class to `Event` that is specifically designed for your view, so it doesn't even *contain* those other properties because your view doesn't need them. You need to change your existing model from `List<Event> Events` to `List<EventViewModel> Events`. I've added the code for this at the top of my answer, which will hopefully make it easier to understand.

Comment: Allright I get that, but I'm getting the following error message now: The object reference not set to an instance of the object. At the Model.EventViewModels.Add(event); in my controller method. I don't really see why the event would be null, I just created it, and I do have Events defined in my database.

Comment: It will be `Model.EventViewModels` that's null, add a `EventViewModels = new List<EventViewModel>();` into your constructor for `OtherMeeting`.

Answer (score 1):

> Now obviously the List Events field will still be a null reference, so
>   I was wondering, how do I add the items I have selected to the List
>   Events field.

You can't with the current structure of your `OtherMeeting` class. You obviously do not want to use `FormCollections` and I suggest you don't if you can **cleanly** do it by just adding an `IEnumerable` of `int`s to your `OtherMeeting` class.

```
public class OtherMeeting {
    public IEnumerable<int> EventIds {get;set;}
}
```

Then on your view use it as

```
@Html.ListBox("EventIds", (MultiSelectList)ViewBag.EventId)
// but I suggest you do this instead
// and let the razor engine take care of the "element naming" for you
@Html.ListBoxFor(x=>x.EventIds, (MultiSelectList)ViewBag.EventId)
```

Comment: So the ViewBag.EventId is now defined as a list of eventid's rather than events right?

Comment: The listbox will only give you a `value`, a primitive type and not a complex type. So you need to feed it with such property (e.g. a list of ints).